# Java8 Stream: Why the method Stream.skip(long n) takes long instead of int as parameter?

Tags: java, java-stream

Here the [definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) of the skip method of Stream :

> skip(long n) Returns a stream consisting of the remaining elements of
>   this stream after discarding the first n elements of the stream.

My question is why the parameter is `long` instead of `int` ?

Here an example :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("1","1","2","3","4");

    stringList.stream()
           .skip(2)
           .forEach(System.out::print);// will prints 234
  }
}
```

Comment: Because streams can be big?

Comment: @LouisWasserman the first thing I thought about it was the size of int, but I were not sure if it was the reason of the designer who implemented this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because not all lists are limited to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` amount of elements.
For example `LinkedList`.

Comment: is ArrayList limited to Integer.MAX_VALUE ? What happen if I add more than this ? is there a control ?

Comment: @Aguid yes, `ArrayList` is limited to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. You will get an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception, when trying to add more elements.

Comment: Considering the per-element overhead of `LinkedList`, it’s not very realistic to expect such a list having more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, but a stream doesn’t need a collection as input: `LongStream.range(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE+1000L).boxed()` or `Stream.iterate(0L, l -> l+1)`, for example…

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you may wish to `skip` on an *infinite stream* in which case you may need a number greater than the maximum an `int` type can hold. Hence it makes complete sense to make such a method accept the largest integer possible. Also, as **[@Joop Eggen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984823/joop-eggen)** has commented, it's consistent with `count()`. of course, one can argue then we could just have both `count()` and `skip()` return/accept an `int` but to leverage streams sometimes we may need the type which can hold the largest integer possible.

Comment: And it is consistent with `count() `.

Comment: @JoopEggen true, I'll include that within the answer.

Comment: You are the one correctly pointing out that streams can be of indefinite length!

Answer (score 2):

That is because `Stream` does not always come from  a collection like `ArrayList` where the maximum length is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` but can also be created over files for each line, practically making the stream to possibly achieve values larger than `int`.

More cases like `LinkedList` also provide you the possibility of going above `Integer.MAX_VALUE` number of elements in the `List`.

Comment: What will be the result of LinkedList.size() in case of its size is higher than Integer.MAX_VALUE ? (The LinkedList is a List)

Comment: @Aguid https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size--